# Retrieving netstat from local server python script

Tags: python, webserver

How do i retrieve the netstat -a data from my python script from a local server. I have tried `subprocess.Popen(['ssh','server','pass','netstat','-a'],stdout=file1)` but it does not work. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have key based authorisation from the desired server where netstat is suppose to run.
In the absence on key based authorisation, the ssh command will return a prompt asking for password.

Below is the link for key based authorisation:
http://wp.uberdose.com/2006/10/16/ssh-automatic-login/

or
http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Once the keys are exchanged, the command mentioned in your question does not require any password and no prompt will occur when you run it.

```
subprocess.Popen(['ssh','server','netstat','-a'],stdout=file1)
```

Comment: No sir. Their is none as it will always prompt for password if the keys are not exchanged. Its the condition of the ssh library and not of the python language.